# possible to grab keywords from a post in the loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

itd be great if someone could help me with this.

Im doing a site for my local football team using wordpress, they want to be able to create regular posts with descriptive match reports . Thats fine. But they also want some of the information to appear on another page with a match report listing as if it were in a table, with just key relevent information, like ...
date | venue | division | hometeam | 3 2 |awayteam | link to report|

Some of this would be fine, ie the date and the link to report , but the problem is the other information is quite specific and not as simple as including `the_title` or something.

The title of their posts wont look the same as what would be on the table. So instead of the `the_content`, `the_title`, etc, Im wondering is it possible to grab certain elements of `the_content`. Or is what im looking to do very complicated?
Im wondering is it possible to implement this using tags?
I want it to be easy for them as possible.
Id really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Any reason not to use custom fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expression to parse the content, but that's not the recommended way of doing it.

The simplest way would be to use "custom fields"
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

And then use

```
get_post_custom($post_id)
```

to get a array of all the different tags, and then display em in a table.

/R

Comment: Thank you thats perfect, I was unaware of custom fields, still getting around wordpress, thats ideal, and to make it better I found a custom field template plugin so that the same fields will appear every time.